# How to store "Infinite data" in a database?

Tags: database

I'm creating a feature that has an option to create infinite bank account transactions by month, for example: A user buy something in 12x parcels, will be created 12 rows on database with relation with this purchase in a table called bank_account_transactions.

Now the problematic scenario: A user has a salary that increase the balance of bank account every month for the rest of his life, how can i store this in database?

I thought store data equivalent to 100 years (12*100=1200) but it is so slow because when the user update the value of his salary, will update 1200 rows in database.

How can I solve this in a performatic way? The project is developed with Nodejs and MongoDB.

Comment: Why would it update 1200 rows? Not that updating 1200 “rows” (confusing verbiage if you’re talking about Mongo) is that slow—but the way transactions work is that a row would be entered per transaction, (a) not for transactions that haven’t happened yet, and (b) transactions don’t modify past transactions. How are you determining there’s a performance problem? Real systems might have tens of thousands of rows per entity (and some will have significantly more).

Comment: I agree with Dave on this. you shouldn't create rows for something you might need. create rows as you need them. i.e. when a user enters the salary increase. Also, if 1200 rows is slow, I think you have a problem with the logic surrounding/calling the db, not the db itself.